# Bizarre colour behaviour on dual screen

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, colors, website, intel-graphics

When loading certain websites in Chrome on my second (furthest right) monitor I'm seeing colour behaviour, where blues are becoming purple. Easy to demonstrate example is the login page below, but also occurs in the browser's menus (see url entry).

[image: Edge Behaviour]
*Edge Behaviour (above), Chrome behaviour (below)*
[image: Chrome Behaviour]

[image: First Monitor]
[image: Second Monitor]

No graphics or colour settings have been changed (Intel built in graphics) so the the only thing I can think that might have happened is Chrome automatic updates. Current version is 61.0.3163.100 (64-bit Windows 10 Pro).

Is there a simple way to stop this behaviour, or any idea what causes it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the "unsplash addon"?

Comment: @DavePenn, yes and sadly no joy

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Disable hardware acceleration for Google Chrome:

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Click the icon with the three horizontal lines at the top-right of the window.
3. Click the Settings option near the bottom of the menu.
4. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click Show advanced settings...
5. Scroll to the bottom of the page again, then remove the check mark next to "Use hardware acceleration when available".
6. Close Google Chrome.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7292182

Comment: That was driving me nuts!